# Grid view caption center alignment

Tags: asp.net, gridview, alignment

I want to set the caption alignment of grid view to the Center of the grid.
CaptionAlign="" property aligns the caption to the "Top", "Left","Bottom" and "Right"

How I can align the Caption to the center of the grid view in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can align the header as:

`<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server">
  <HeaderStyle  HorizontalAlign="Right" />`

To align cell:

`ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"`

for vertical align:

`ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Right`

Comment: Above changes align the grid view caption to the Right side and not to the Center of the Grid View

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to use CSS. As an example:

```
<style>
    table caption {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<asp:GridView ID="YourGrid" runat="server" Caption="Caption is now centered">
</asp:GridView>
```

Note: though the style says "table caption", the gridview ultimately gets rendered as a table in the browser, so it will work. (for me anyway)